# Bash — locate file, awk copy not working correctly

Tags: bash, awk, cp

I'm trying to use the following to locate a file then copy the first result to the directory that is set by $dir. It works fine when I don't set a variable and use an absolute path, but that's not what I need.

**This doesn't work:**

```
dir="/path/to/destination/";
mkdir "$dir";
locate -l 1 target_file.txt | awk '{print "cp " $1 $dir " "}' | sh
```

error message is:

```
awk: illegal field $(), name "dir"
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
cp: fts_open: No such file or directory
```

**This works:**

```
locate -l 1 target_file.txt | awk '{print "cp " $1 " /path/to/destination/"}' | sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an `awk` script, you don't use `$` to prefix variables; you use it to refer to fields in the line of input.

```
dir="/path/to/destination/";
mkdir "$dir";
locate -l 1 target_file.txt | awk -v dir="$dir" '{print "cp",  $1, dir}' | sh
```

This will work OK as long as you have no spaces in your names.

```
dir="/path/to/destination/";
mkdir "$dir";
locate -l 1 target_file.txt | awk -v dir="$dir" '{printf "cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $1, dir}' | sh
```

Unless I screwed up the backslashes, that should work with spaces etc in file names.  The whole pipeline will be screwed up if someone is unkind enough to put a newline into a file name.

Comment: @Johnathan — it works now, although I still get an error or warning `cp: fts_open: No such file or directory`. Any idea what would be causing that? thanks very much.

Comment: Not really got much idea.  I'd start by debugging with `sh -x` in place of `sh` at the end of the command.  My suspicion would be that your `locate` command is saying there should be a file `fts_open` but `cp` can't find it.  To debug that, I'd insert `| tee locate.log` after `target_file.txt` and then scrutinize the `locate.log` file after the command is run.

Comment: Interesting. At least it works now per your help, and I'll definitely try the suggestions you've mentioned. Once again, thank you! :)