# Find a specific file then pipe to stdout/awk

Tags: bash, find, stdout

I'm looking for a way to traverse directories recursively to find a specific file, then stop the search and pipe the filename path to an awk function or something similar. [I asked a question earlier that was similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943713/bash-locate-file-awk-copy-not-working-correctly), but after testing on machines other than mine it turns out the `locate` command isn't going to work since not everyone uses it on their system.

Code that I used with locate:

```
dir="/path/to/destination/";
mkdir "$dir";
locate -l 1 target_file.txt | \
   awk -v dir="$dir" '{printf "cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $1, dir}' | \
   sh
```

Comment: you could use find instead of locate

Comment: @Heisenbug — I thought about that, but couldn't really find something that was specific to finding one file. Would I use it in the same manner as I did with `locate`? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `find(1)` command will do it. To only get one line, use `head(1)`.

```
dir="/path/to/destination/";
mkdir "$dir";
find /path/location -name target_file.txt |
    head -n 1 |
    awk -v dir="$dir" '{printf "cp \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", $1, dir}' |
    sh
```

Comment: nice — one question though; since locate more or less finds the file without specifying a starting directory how would I achieve this with your example? i.e. start searching at `/path/location/`

Comment: @SamOlde You change the `.` to `/path/location`. I edited the answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

If you know only one file exists then you can use

`find ./ -name "target_file.txt" -exec cp -r {} $dir \;`

And if you are not sure, use head to limit 1 and use xargs

`find ./ -name "target_file.txt" | head -1 | xargs -I {} cp -r {} $dir/`

Comment: I know more than one file exists, although I just want to get the result of the first one found. Thanks for the examples; I wish the find was as fast as `locate` :-/

Comment: Find could be made fast by adding extra switches. For example if you know that the file will not be more than two dir levels down you can add  -maxdepth 2 and also limit find to searching only file by using -type f. So in All you can try find ./ -name "target_file.txt" -type f -maxdepth 2 | head -1 | xargs -I {} cp -r {} $dir/

Comment: good information for sure; even with the switches it's still not as fast as i'd like it to be. I appreciate you taking the time to mention what you have. :)